# How to make subdivision modifier unaffected by a vertice on an edge

Tags: subdivision-surface

So I did a loop cut on an edge on a mesh, that has the subdivision surface modifier turned on. I want the vertice that was created, to not affect the subsurf modifier. Now, the modifier takes the edge all the way to the vertice, and not making it curve as I would hope.
It's worth noticing, that I creased the edge to 1.00.

Here's some screenshots, so you better can understand my problem:
[image: My mesh seen from the side]
This is the mesh seen from the side.

[image: Mesh seen from the top]
This is the mesh seen from the top. I have selected the problem causing vertice.

[image: The vertice is selected. Mesh seen from angled front]
Here, I have selected the vertice.

[image: Mesh seen from bottom]
I want the edge to curve like this one.

Let me know, if I can provide any more information!

Basically, if possible, the vertice should not affect the subsurf modifier as it does. It should just be there and act like it wasn't there.

Hope some of you want to take your time answering my question!

Comment: Not sure to understand what you want to do. It seems that you created a loop cut, But this cut does not go over all the faces. Like you want an additional subdiv for one face but not for the other one sharing this same vertex? Could you explain a bit more and eventually upload your blend file (use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to upload).

Comment: I wan't the edge, that the vertice is sitting on (image 2 and 3), to curve like the one on the last image. If I make the loop cut goes over the other edges, it creates a bended circle which I don't want.